# How to get longest match of a pattern of overlapping options?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am dealing with Python regular expressions where I am trying to get the longest match of a pattern that includes overlapping options.

Consider this example:

```
import re
task = "s290_fpga_simv_test_verilog"
pattern_str = "(s290|s290_fpga|s289|s289_fpga|s274|s274_fpga)"
result = re.match(pattern_str, task)
print(result.group(1))
```

It gives me the output `s290` where I am expecting the longer `s290_fpga`. What is necessary to get the longest possible match?

Comment: It matches in order... put the longer patterns first...

Comment: Cant we make it more robust ? Actually for simplicity I hardcoded the pattern list. In my case that list is dynamic which comes from some external API. So order can't guarantee.

Comment: Yes... take the list and sort it by descending length to create your pattern string...

Comment: A different approach is to avoid alternation altogether: `r"(s2[987][094](_fpga)?)"`

Answer (score 0):

Reverse your order of matches so you become less specific as you go to right. Your code is correct but the `re.match()` finds a match at `s290` and then stops. If you want the result `s290_fpga`swap your order to:

```py
"(s290_fpga|s290 etc...)"
```